# Function not updating variable in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am unable to solve this problem.

This is my main page controller:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myContacts', [
    'ngRoute',
    'firebase',
    'contacts.mycontacts'
])

.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/contacts'});
}]);
```

This is my second or contacts controller:

```
angular.module('contacts.mycontacts', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/contacts', {
        templateUrl: 'contacts/contacts.html',
        controller: 'contactsCtrl'
    });
}])

.controller('contactsCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.showAddForm = function(){
        console.log($scope.addFormShow); // gives me undefined every time
        $scope.addFormShow = true;
        console.log($scope.addFormShow); // gives me true
    }
    console.log($scope.addFormShow); //gives me undefined 
}]);
```

and this is my HTML of contacts:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller='contactsCtrl'>
<div ng-show="addFormShow"> the Add Button get a  click from user </div>
<div class="small-12 large-2 columns">
    <a class="button large" href="#" ng-click="showAddForm()">+  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

As u can see in the modulel->contacts.mycontacts->controller , this is the problem function

```
$scope.showAddForm = function(){ console.log($scope.addFormShow); // gives me undefined every time
$scope.addFormShow = true;
console.log($scope.addFormShow); // gives me true 
}   
console.log($scope.addFormShow); //gives me undefined
```

HTML from contacts under ng-view where the problem is occurring // the above function is not updating addFormShow in below HTML

```
<div class="row" ng-controller='contactsCtrl'>
<div ng-show="addFormShow"> the Add Button get a  click from user </div>
<div class="small-12 large-2 columns">
    <a class="button large" href="#" ng-click="showAddForm()">+  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should state a clear problem and then formulate a question. Don't just give code.

Comment: Dear @ssc-hrep3, as mentioned in the heading my function is not updating my variable , i dont know where is the problem . As u can see in the modulel->contacts.mycontacts->controller , this is the problem function `$scope.showAddForm = function(addFormShow){
        console.log($scope.addFormShow); // gives me undefined every time
        $scope.addFormShow = true;
        console.log($scope.addFormShow); // gives me true
    }
    console.log($scope.addFormShow); //gives me undefined
`
scroll up for better view of code , thanks

Comment: please clear your question

Comment: @HD.. i made some changes regarding explaining my problem , hope i elaborated my problem , if still false please let me know

Comment: Thanks u every body thank , thank u , problem is just solved

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior.
The order you're writing the function and the console.log doesn't matter.

What's happening is that you're logging a variable which is not defined at that time. Then maybe call the function and get again undefined, assign it, and get true.

I strongly suggest you follow [John's papa guidelines](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1) to write your code.

To "fix" whatever issue you have, define the variable in the top of your controller

```
    .controller('contactsCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {

    $scope.addFormShow = false;

    $scope.showAddForm = function showAddForm(){ //I recommend you name your functions
        console.log($scope.addFormShow); // gives you false
        $scope.addFormShow = true;
        console.log($scope.addFormShow); // gives me true
    }
    console.log($scope.addFormShow); //gives you false
}]);
```

Comment: Dugler , thanks for you line "This is the expected behavior. "

Answer (score 0):

just solved the problem it was due to href="#"

```
 <a class="button large" href="#"ng-click="showAddForm()">+  </a>
```

changed it to

```
 <a class="button large" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="showAddForm()">+</a>
```